# How can I implement h264 video stream encapsulation in flv format and push it using WebSocket in iOS using native lightweight code?

Tags: h.264, flv, muxer, streaming-flv-video

As the title, I am an iOS developer now, but I know nothing about the packaging of flv format, but there are no similar code cases in the community. Some are just some heavy third-party libraries based on rtmp or ffmpeg, so there is no lightweight native code packaging. I want a code implementation case of objc or C, so powerful netizens can help me.

I tried to encapsulate it, but the encapsulated video can't be played because of the lack of script tag and MetaData. I expect to get a high-quality code case answer, and I will give back to the community a hundred times.

Comment: _"The encapsulated video can't be played because of the lack of Script tag and MetaData"_ You don't need **Script** tag or **onMetadata** tag in order to play an FLV video. **(1)** Show a small download link for our checking of your test FLV output. A few seconds or minutes is enough to see the problem.  **(2)** Does reading this [FLV specification](https://ossrs.io/lts/en-us/assets/files/flv_v10_1-5244d3059e5425eb03a15eb24537bd59.pdf) help you in some way? Ask anything about the specs if stuck on a page.